# Doubt in expansion of integral

Tags: statistical-mechanics

While solving for the chemical potential of a fermi gas at $T\ne 0$, we first take

$$n = \int_0^{\mu}g(\epsilon)d\epsilon+(\pi^2/6)(k_BT^2)g'(\mu)+O(T^4)$$

Which is obtained by the Sommerfeld expansion. After this step, the author has stated the approximation,
$$\int_0^{\mu}H(\epsilon)d\epsilon = \int_0^{\epsilon_F}H(\epsilon)d\epsilon + (\mu-\epsilon_F)H(\epsilon_F)$$
I am not able to understand this approximation. Anyone, please help.

Answer (score 2):

I believe they are assuming that $H(\epsilon)$ becomes a constant above $\epsilon > \epsilon_{f}$, so you can split the integral and the integral above $\epsilon_{f}$ when integrating you just get $H(\epsilon_{f})(\mu - \epsilon_{f})$

Comment: Not so much constant as slowly varying. You assume that $\mu-\epsilon_F$ is small and the corrections from derivatives of $H$ will be of higher order so you neglect them

Comment: @user3725600 so they are Taylor expanding the integral and neglecting the higer order terms. Got it.Thanks.

Comment: @SumitGupta Actually, the Taylor expansion is not made on the original integral, but only on the integral from $\epsilon_F$ to $\mu$.